# How to implements two strategies with passportjs

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have two model in my node/express app :

1. **User** model (simple user authenticated)
2. **Manager** model (user with different rights and different fields)

I want to use passport to authenticated them :

1. **User** with couple : **Username / Password**
2. **Manager** with couple : **Email / Password**

I correctly implemented PassportJS for the User model but now I try to do the same for Manager model.

```
exports.postlogin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('user', function(err, user, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!user) {
            req.session.messages =  [info.message];
            return res.redirect('/login')
        }
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
};

exports.postlogin = function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('manager', function(err, manager, info) {
        if (err) { return next(err) }
        if (!manager) {
            req.session.messages =  [info.message];
            return res.redirect('/manager_signup')
        }
        req.logIn(manager, function(err) {
            if (err) { return next(err); }
            return res.redirect('/');
        });
    })(req, res, next);
};
```

The two strategies :

```
passport.use('user', new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    UserModel.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown user ' + username }); }
        user.comparePassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if(isMatch) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));

passport.use('manager', new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'manager_signin_email', passwordField: 'manager_signin_password'},function(manager_signin_email, manager_signin_password, done) {
    ManagerModel.findOne({ email: manager_signin_email }, function(err, manager) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!manager) { return done(null, false, { message: 'Unknown manager ' + manager_signin_email }); }
        manager.comparePassword(manager_signin_password, function(err, isMatch) {
            if (err) return done(err);
            if(isMatch) {
                console.log('Manager login OK : ' + manager_signin_email);
                return done(null, manager);
            } else {
                return done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid password' });
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

The problem is for Serialize/Deserialize.
For User I have this :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    UserModel.findById(id, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

But I don't know how to do for Manager model.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something like this when serializing:

```
if (isUser(user)) {
    // serialize user
    done(null, "user_"+user.id );
  } else if (isManager(user)) {
    // serialize manager
    done(null, "manager_"+user.id );

  }
```

And then check the prefix when deserializing.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an open issue for what you want (https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/148) .

Alternatively you could change you serialize method to include information if it's user or manager not only user id  and when deserializing read that info and load user/manager from proper model.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still stumbling upon this. You can check the type of the object you are serializing.  Note all there of by objects are generalized in to a PrincipleInfo object.

```
function PrincipleInfo(principleId, principleType, details) {
    this.principleId = principleId;
    this.principleType = principleType;
    this.details = details;
}

passport.serializeUser(function (userObjectThing, done) {
    //userObjectThing could be a User or a Sponsor
    var principleType = "user";
    var userPrototype =  Object.getPrototypeOf(userObjectThing);
    if (userPrototype === User.prototype) {
        principleType = "user";
    } else if (userPrototype === Sponsor.prototype) {
        principleType = "sponsor";
    } else if (userPrototype === Admin.prototype) {
        principleType = "admin";
    }

    var principleInfo = new PrincipleInfo(userObjectThing.id, principleType, '');
    done(null,principleInfo);
});

    passport.deserializeUser(function (principleInfo, done) {

        if (principleInfo.principleType == 'user') {
            User.findOne({
                _id: principleInfo.principleId
            }, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, user) { // don't ever give out the password or salt
                done(err, user);
            });
        } else if (principleInfo.principleType == 'sponsor') {
            Sponsor.findOne({
                _id: principleInfo.principleId
            }, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, user) { // don't ever give out the password or salt
                done(err, user);
            });
        } else if (principleInfo.principleType == 'admin') {
            Admin.findOne({
                _id: principleInfo.principleId
            }, '-salt -hashedPassword', function (err, user) { // don't ever give out the password or salt
                done(err, user);
            });
        }

    });
```